# How to open HTML on Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

Q1) How do i open this file as browser and test it?

Q2) How do i directly open this on Chrome from Eclipse and Test it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjz7M.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists as a file in your file system. Browse there with Windows File Explorer and open it with the program you wish (Chrome in this case).

In Eclipse, you can also open the context menu on the file, and choose "Open with >" and then either "System Editor" or "Other..." and choose from "External programs".